# PHP PDO INSERT INTO not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem while inserting datas in MySQL database with PDO.
I have no error, it just seems to didn't have inserted datas in the table when I select them after execute the code with MySQL in terminal.
I've tried solutions in answers on stackoverflow, like wraping name and description in backticks, but it's still not working
Here is my sql columns : 
[image: sql columns]

Here is the code :

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO cities (`name`, departement, province, lat, long, `description`, poi_id) VALUES(`:name`, :departement, :province, :lat, :long, `:description`, :poi_id)");
    $query = $query->execute([
        "name" => $name,
        "departement" => $code_dpt,
        "province" => (int)$provinces[$departements[$code_dpt]],
        "lat" => $lat,
        "long" => $long,
        "description" => $description,
        "poi_id" => (int)$poi_id
    ]);
```

Comment: Your placeholders shouldn't have any form of quotes - `\`:name\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.
First, I've enabled errors like this :

```php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bpfmgr', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

I was using a property named `long` for longitude, but it's a MySQL reserved keyword, so it mades errors. I've added backticks to wrap `long` and that's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO cities (`name`, departement, province, lat, long, `description`, poi_id) VALUES(:name, :departement, :province, :lat, :long, :description, :poi_id)");
$query->execute([
        ':name' => $name,
        ':departement' => $code_dpt,
        ':province' => (int)$provinces[$departements[$code_dpt]],
        ':lat' => $lat,
        ':long' => $long,
        ':description' => $description,
        ':poi_id' => (int)$poi_id
    ]);
```

use placeholder in `execute` function.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried but it's still not working